# How to Generate boxplot for everyrow in the give table in R?

Tags: r, matrix, boxplot

I have data in the following format in a text file:

```
#Position   Mean    Median  Lower_Quartile  Upper_Quartile  10th_Percentile 90th_Percentile
1   33.79097948291701   34.0    34.0    34.0    34.0    34.0
2   33.79898508246205   34.0    34.0    34.0    34.0    34.0
3   33.81967715123146   34.0    34.0    34.0    34.0    34.0
4   33.821820727065926  34.0    34.0    34.0    34.0    34.0
5   33.82225819152194   34.0    34.0    34.0    34.0    34.0
6   37.62032459862636   38.0    38.0    38.0    38.0    38.0
7   37.61853099435671   38.0    38.0    38.0    38.0    38.0
8   37.574522070081805  38.0    38.0    38.0    38.0    38.0
9   37.54608688044097   38.0    38.0    38.0    37.0    38.0
```

Each row is used to generate a boxplot. I want to generate a graph that shows boxplots from all the rows from above table in one graph,ordered by the position. The default boxplot option loads each column into a boxplot. How to change that?

My initial approaches where using the default boxplot command,yielding me with boxplot for each column.

Comment: Can you provide data in easily copy/pastable form? What have you tried and where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `df` contains your data, you could try

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(as.factor(Position))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = X10th_Percentile, lower = Lower_Quartile, middle = Median, upper = Upper_Quartile, ymax =X90th_Percentile), stat = "identity")
```